# Is there a way to create a shortcut for files?

Tags: shortcuts

I have several books or files which I want to open many times, is there a way which I can remember the files and open them by one click?

I am using ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Open all the files at once? What types of files are they?

Answer (score 1):

You can write a shell script and have it open the files for you.  Depending on your interface, there are various ways to add this to your desktop or menu.

```
#! /usr/bin/bash

FILES="
file1
file2
"

# Option 1 - open files individually
for file in ${FILES}; do 
    less $file
done

# Option 2 - open files at once
less ${FILES}

# EOF
```

Some tools will remember the files you had open, and open them when you restart the tool.  Others have a recent file list that allows you to quickly reopen a file you recently had open.